# Can I combine isolated scope and inherited scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

is it possible to combine isolated scope and inherited scope?

I have the following structure:

```
<my-parent-directive>
    <my-directive ng-repeat="foo in foos" foo="foo"></my-directive>
</my-parent-directive>


app.module("app").directive("myParentDirective", function(){
   return {
       //other directive properties
       controller: function($scope) {
                      $scope.myFunc(){//function I want to call from child element
                        //dostuff
                      };
       },
       link: function($scope){
            $scope.foos = ["foo", "bar"];
       }
   };
});

app.module("app").directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
       //other directive properties
       scope : {foo: "="},
       template: "<button ng-click='doStuff()'>doStuff</button>",
       controller: function($scope){ //need controller here to do other stuff as well},
       link: function($scope){
            $scope.doStuff = function() {
               //do stuff plus call myFunc
               $scope.myFunc();//declared in "parent scope". This does not work
            }
       }
    };
});
```

So yeah. Is there a way to do this?

I use isolated scope to get "foo" from the ng-repeat of the parent scope's "foos"-array.

Previously i have emitted an event from the child element and listened on the "parent", but i would rather do it using scope. Is there a way or do I need to use event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can! Your inner directive has isolated scope, so can't see anything outside of itself, but you can pass in the function to your directive with the '&' binding, so your directive might look something like:

```
<my-directive foo="func()"></my-directive>
```

I've done you a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/454ax0cs/).